# If there is a way to pre-calculate SQL View in order to speed-up queries from it?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, select, view

I perform numerous different SELECTs from an SQLite VIEW (dynamic table) using a cycle in Python. The underlying SQL query for the VIEW takes about 5 seconds to complete. According to my current understanding, the VIEW is recalculated every time, when I perform a SELECT from it. Since within the Python cycle, I do not update any tables, I wonder if there is a way to "freeze" (precalculate) the VIEW as a static table, perform fast SELECTs from it and after "release" it.

Before I tried to optimize the underlying query code of the VIEW and managed to reduce the execution time from 16 to 5 seconds. I tried also to find in Internet commands similar to  "BEGIN;" and "COMMIT;" which do a great job for updating the tables, but could not find any.

My query which I perform from the Python loop looks like that:

```sql
SELECT date, spread FROM futures_spreads_close 
WHERE commodity_id=? AND exp_month_id=? AND exp_year=? 
ORDER BY date;
```

where the questions marks are the loop indexes.

If I re-implement all the logic from the VIEW into the Python code, I can have spped-up for about 100 times. However, I would like to keep all the logic inside the SQL. I believe that there is a more efficient way to perform queries on a VIEW.

Comment: In a database that supports materialized views, the answer is "yes".  SQLite is not one of those databases.

Comment: there is flexview; which is a similar concept as materialized views in MySQL.

Comment: @SegejKosov . . . Is `futures_spreads_close` a view?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running multiple queries using a slow view whose rows aren't going to change between the different queries, you can materialize it by caching the view's rows in a temporary table, and use that table in the queries:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE mat_view AS SELECT * FROM actual_view;
-- Create indexes if needed
```

Temporary tables are dropped when you close the database connection, or you can explicitly `DROP` it when done with the queries that use it.